# Error while configuring PHP with existing apache

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, php

I am receiving this message:

`configure: error: Invalid Apache directory - unable to find httpd.h under /usr/lib64/httpd/`

after executing the following command:

`./configure --with-apache=/usr/lib64/httpd/`

I don't know where is the top-level DIR on my already installed apache. The apache service is already installed on my CentOS 6.5 server from repository using `yum install httpd`.

- Apache version 2.2.15-31
- PHP version 5.4.25

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the final solution for my question:

Installing httpd-devel package from repository `yum install httpd-devel`, where the headers of the apache are included.

Configuring php with apxs2: `./configure --with-apxs`.

And last step is adding the following lines in the VirtualHost in the httpd.conf file (or in the included .conf files):

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Not sure you needed `httpd-devel` package but if it's working, that's cool :) (set your own response as accepted so future viewers will have the answer)

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGillier `yum install httpd` doesn't install `apxs`. It's only installed by `yum install httpd-devel`. So `httpd-devel` is needed.

Answer (score 2):

If your apache is already built and configured, you should compile PHP as a shared module instead of a static one.

Overhead is slightly superior but you'll be able to upgrade each component separately.

Configure example:

```
$ ./configure --with-apxs=<path to apxs binary in apache/http bindir>
```

Forgot one thing : your apache has to be compiled with mod_so enabled to use dynamic modules built with apxs

Comment: He doesn't have apxs, he don't have even apache headers...

Comment: @PeterHorvath apxs is already installed on my server and httpd-devel packages is installed...

Comment: If apache is installed and running, apxs has to be there too, else there is a major problem. It's a binary built at same time as httpd.

Comment: @bedel7 Ok, I extended my answer so.

Comment: Isn't apxs only for the apache module compilation needed?

Comment: Nope, apxs is used to build external modules for apache :) You build your apache with mod_so then you build modules with apxs and, finally, add them to apache with LoadModule command

Comment: Php is an external module for apache, so it requires the apxs.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compile things for apache - this time, php -, you need to have the headers of the apache to do that. They are some like "apache-dev" or "apache2-devel" or "libapache2-devel", or similar named package. *This package you have to install.*

This development package will contain the apxs binary, which will be probably automatically found by the php configuration scripts.

*EXTENSION:*
Second, read the `./configure --help` output of the php source code carefully. As I can remember, as if the were some difference between the `--with-apache`, `--with-apache2` or `--with-apxs` flags. Are you sure you won't compile for apache1 accidentally?

*EXTENSION #2:*
Maybe you could get the source php package of your distribution as well, at least to find out, how does this the (re)compilation.

Comment: @PeterSmith I am supposing that --with-apache and --with-apache2 is meaning the apache version (1.x.x or 2.x.x). Right?

Comment: @bedel7 Yes. Read the configure script output carefully.

Comment: @PeterSmith weird, `configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-apache2`. There aren't any entry for --with-apach2...

Comment: @bedel7 I write third time: read the configure output carefully. You won't get a fourth. And if you are satisfied with an answer, you had to accept/upvote that.